# The mathematical similarity and difference between code-based PKE and multivariate DSS

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, multivariate-cryptography, code-based-cryptography

In code-based public key encryption schemes, a public key is formed by matrix-multiplying 2 linear matrices to the left and right side of a easily decodeable error-correcting code, so that it'll be difficult to extract useful information that may be used to decrypt ciphertexts.

In multivariate digital signature schemes, a public key is formed by compositing linear equation systems to the inner and outter parts of a easily solvable multivariate (usually quadratic) equation system, so that the resulting composition cannot be easily reversed.

From my understanding, the composition with linear systems is the biggest similarity between code-based PKE and multivariate DSS, and I wonder:

1. Is there any other aspect where code-based and multivariate cryptosystems are similar?
2. What are the important differences between code-based and multivariate cryptosystems?

Answer (score 2):

Multivariate schemes tipically work with a central polynomial map $\mathcal{F}(X) : F_2^n \mapsto F_2^m$ which is a quadratic map that defines $m$ quadratic equations on $n$ variables. Then select $T,S$ as invertible affine transformations. The public key $P(X) = T \circ F \circ S(X)$ is written as $m$ quadratic forms in $n$ variables over $F_2$.

However, as every Quadratic Form $q_i(X)=X^T Q_i X$ can be linearised using Tensors, this is, a dot product of $\overline{q_i}(x \otimes x)$ where $\overline{q_i}$ is the $n^2$ vector reshape of the matrix $q_i$.

Then rewrite the public key as a $m \times n^2$ matrix $\overline{P}$ where the $i$th row encodes the $i$-th columns of the quadratic forms. This is a rectangular matrix which doesn't allow an attacker to compute the input value $X$ from the output $Y$. From here the goal is to either attempt to solve by obtaining the affine transformations $(T,S)$ which we refer to the *Isomorphism of Polynomials* ($\mathcal{IP}$), solving the underlying non-linear quadratic system over $F_2$, which is a subinstance of the **PoSSo** problem, called the $\mathcal{MQ}$ problem or studying the MinRank $\mathcal{MR}$ problem.

For example, an HFE public key can be computed using pure Linear Algebra, without working in Polynomial Rings and Finite Fields. Either deriving the Quadratic Forms as I did [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348372778_Fast_Computing_of_Quadratic_Forms_of_HFE_Polynomials_over_fields_of_characteristic_two) or using Tensors. But you still need to apply Berlekamp's to find roots over $F_q$.